# Client connects and receives websocket data but can not send

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, network-programming

I have this piece of code running on several devices without issue. But one device is having a problem that is driving me insane.

The client device can connect to the websocket server and receives data but when I try and send data back, the server does not receive any data. The results are intermittent but most of the time get no response; however, I never lose my SSH connection to the client device. No error messages, I just see my client device receiving a request from the server then sending data but the server showing nothing. When I restart the client program, I get a response.

Code is dead simple:

```
Server:
socket.emit('get settings',data); //client receives this!
socket.on('load settings', function (data) {
  console.log("load settings |",data.mac); //no response from client
  device_socket.emit('loaded settings',data);
});

Client:
var relay = require('socket.io-client')("http://"+relay_server+":"+relay_port);
relay.on('get settings', function (data) {
  relay.emit('load settings', settings); //server never gets this!
  console.log("sending settings"); //this is reached without error
});
```

server code: https://github.com/physiii/open-automation/blob/master/relay/socket.js

client code: https://github.com/physiii/open-automation/blob/master/gateway/socket.js

UPDATE: I fixed the problem however I do not understand why so I'm leaving it unanswered. My program works as follows:

> devices[n] <---sockets[n]---> relay <---socket---> angular.js

If you read the problem above it seems obvious the issue is between the device and socket (remember only one device is having issues). I realized the device worked when I changed the server port. After investigation, I changed the angular.js connection to the server (which I use location.host to get) and got it working but I have no idea why it causes the behavior described above:

One line change to userinfo.js (can't post link because of stupid reputation points)

I changed this:

```
  $rootScope.server_address = location.host;  
  var parts = $rootScope.server_address.split(":");
  $rootScope.server_ip = parts[0];
  $rootScope.port = parts[1];
  var relay_socket = io.connect("http://" + $rootScope.server_address + ":" + $rootScope.port);
```

To this:

```
  $rootScope.server_address = location.host;  
  var parts = $rootScope.server_address.split(":");
  $rootScope.server_ip = parts[0];
  $rootScope.port = parts[1] || 80;
  var relay_socket = io.connect("http://" + $rootScope.server_address + ":" + $rootScope.port);
```

Now obviously it needed to be changed because when I don't specify a port io.connect("domain.com:") has a trailing ":" but why this only affected one device is a mystery to me.

Comment: UPDATE: When I change the server port from 80 to 5000, it works. Still don't know why or how to fix this yet. And I don't understand why this is the only device with an issue but that has to be a clue.

Comment: Check firewall rule for incomming and outcomming on PORT which used by your server. Or you can try change message name `load settings` to another and test again.

Comment: I'm on a mobile connection, so don't have access to ports: see my update

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue appears because you use 'ws' module at back-end and 'socket-io' in front-end.

I remember using 'ws' once, and I used native web-sockets, without any modules in front-end. As far as I used 'socket-io', I used it for both front and back end.

And you have rather complex code there. I can suggest to comment out all. Start from simple 'echo' server (ping-pong) and then extend functionality.

Comment: I am using the 'ws' module for something else. I use 'socket.io' for issue at hand. See line 258 here: https://github.com/physiii/open-automation/blob/master/relay/socket.js  I will make a simple test as you suggested. Just odd that this is the only device with an issue even though it's a raspberry pi 3 like the rest of the devices. It's running through a mobile connection but so are the others.